# Compiler doesn't find member of llvm:function

Tags: clang, llvm

I am trying to compile the [Chapter8 of llvm Kaleidoscope tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl08.html), but the compiler says

```
yuandong@DESKTOP-VA6HJ6B:/mnt/c/llvm/llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope/Chapter8$ clang -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags -
-ldflags --system-libs --libs all` -o toy
toy.cpp:870:16: error: no member named 'insert' in 'llvm::Function'
  TheFunction->insert(TheFunction->end(), ElseBB);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
toy.cpp:882:16: error: no member named 'insert' in 'llvm::Function'
  TheFunction->insert(TheFunction->end(), MergeBB);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
toy.cpp:1245:13: error: no template named 'optional' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'Optional'?
  auto RM = std::optional<Reloc::Model>();
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Optional
/usr/lib/llvm-14/include/llvm/BinaryFormat/Dwarf.h:33:28: note: 'Optional' declared here
template<typename T> class Optional;
```

But I do find the implementation of `insert` in `Function.h`

```
  /// Insert \p BB in the basic block list at \p Position. \Returns an iterator
  /// to the newly inserted BB.
  Function::iterator insert(Function::iterator Position, BasicBlock *BB) {
    return BasicBlocks.insert(Position, BB);
  }
```

Comment: Which LLVM version are you using ? Function::insert was introduced in https://reviews.llvm.org/rG80f2f1eabc491cde39d543e4ebda93e2d2974d1f the 15 of Dec 2022. Older LLVM versions (older than LLVM 17 I think) won't have this method. My advice is that, for development, it's better to build LLVM from its sources instead of using the version downloaded by the package manager.